# Добавление кнопки itunes

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Как добавить кнопку `itunes`, чтобы переход был на страничку?

Comment: Кнопка "Поделиться через iTunes"? Что она должна, по вашему мнению, делать?

Answer (score 2):

Почти не ясно, что Вам нужно и для чего. Но как я понял - Вы хотите добавить кнопку в приложение или страницу сайта, клик по которой перекидывал бы пользователя в магазин Apple. Если так, то Вам понадобится сама кнопка и ссылка на некоторое приложение в магазине Apple.

1) Для страницы сайта: необходимо добавить на страницу графический элемент (он же - Ваша кнопка), и присвоить ей статус гиперссылки по адресу, собственно, с сайта iTunes.

2) Для приложения: необходимо добавить графический элемент типа picturebox, но в коде элемента picturebox1_click прописать код, открывающий ссылку через браузер.

Вот Вам самая обобщённая теория. Может помочь, если Вы добавляете кнопку в визуальных редакторах. На будущее: поясняйте цель Вашей задачи, язык программирования, и какими ресурсами на редактирование страниц/приложений Вы обладаете.